# XLSX.write error on angular.js n.t.match is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, excel, xlsx

I've been trying to create an `.xlsx` file using the XLSX lib. But when I tried to write a XLSX file I get this error message:

```
TypeError: n.t.match is not a function
 at Ps (xlsx.full.min.js:14)
 at Jd (xlsx.full.min.js:18)
 at Sv (xlsx.full.min.js:21)
 at Fv (xlsx.full.min.js:21)
 at Object.Uv [as write] (xlsx.full.min.js:21)
 at n.scope.download (excelExport.js:100)
 at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:212), <anonymous>:4:215)
 at f (angular.js:253)
 at n.$eval (angular.js:133)
 at n.$apply (angular.js:133)
```

Here is part of my code :

```
   function getSheet(data, opts) {
       var ws = {};
       var range = {s: {c:10000000, r:10000000}, e: {c:0, r:0 }};
       for(var R = 0; R != data.length; ++R) {

            for(var C = 0; C != data[R].length; ++C) {

                if(range.s.r > R) range.s.r = R;
                if(range.s.c > C) range.s.c = C;
                if(range.e.r < R) range.e.r = R;
                if(range.e.c < C) range.e.c = C;

                var cell = {v: data[R][C] };
                if(cell.v == null) continue;

                    var cell_address = {c:C,r:R}
                    var cell_ref = XLSX.utils.encode_cell(cell_address);
                            
                    if(typeof cell.v === 'number') cell.t = 'n';
                    else if(typeof cell.v === 'boolean') cell.t = 'b';
                    else if(cell.v instanceof Date) {
                        cell.t = 'n'; cell.z = XLSX.SSF._table[14];
                        cell.v = datenum(cell.v);
                    }
                    else {cell.t = 's';}                       
                    ws[cell_ref] = cell;
                }
            }
                    
            if(range.s.c < 10000000) ws['!ref'] = XLSX.utils.encode_range(range);
            return ws;
    };

    function Workbook(){

        if(!(this instanceof Workbook)) return new Workbook();
        this.SheetNames = [];
        this.Sheets = {}
    }
```

In the following code I got this error

```
94 var wb = new Workbook(), ws = getSheet(scope.data(), scope.options);
95 /* add worksheet to workbook */
96 wb.SheetNames.push(scope.fileName);
97 wb.Sheets[scope.fileName] = ws;

100 var wbout = XLSX.write(wb, {bookType:'xlsx', bookSST:true, type: 'binary'});
```

Does anyone knows about this error? I have been searching for solutions but seen no one getting this before.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in data structure that I've built to make the `.xls` file

I've built a list of lists where each line represent a line on the `.xls` file,
and when I built one of these lines, I made a mistake and wrongly concatenated two lists, creating a list whose last element is another list.